# How to configure Docker Compose to run Android integration tests in the emulator during the GitLab CI pipeline?

Tags: android, docker, docker-compose, android-emulator, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to set up GitLab CI to run Android integration tests.

First I tried to do everything in .gitlab-ci.yml:

1. Create and boot the emulator.
2. Run tests on it.

But I ran into a problem. The emulator took more than 15 minutes to boot, which was unacceptable.

Then my plan was to keep the emulator always ready - boot the emulator in a docker container and connect to it from another container with gitlab-runner.
To do this, I used docker-compose to create a local network between the two containers.
But no matter what I try, I can't connect to the emulator from gitlab-runner container. What am I doing wrong?

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  android-emulator:
    image: android-emulator
    privileged: true
    expose:
      - "8554"
      - "5554"
      - "5555"
  
  gitlab-runner:
    image: mobile-runner
    depends_on:
      - android-emulator
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

Android Emulator Dockerfile

```
FROM thyrlian/android-sdk

ARG arch="x86_64"
ARG target="google_apis"
ARG deviceName="android_emulator"
ARG deviceType="pixel"
ARG maxApiLevel=33
ARG buildToolsVersion="$maxApiLevel.0.2"

ENV DEVICE_NAME=${deviceName}

COPY --chmod=777 start_emulator.sh /usr/local/bin/start_emulator.sh

RUN sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-${maxApiLevel}"
RUN echo "y" | sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-${maxApiLevel};${target};${arch}"
RUN sdkmanager --update && \ 
    echo "y" | sdkmanager --licenses
RUN echo "no" | avdmanager -v create avd --force --name $DEVICE_NAME --package "system-images;android-${maxApiLevel};${target};${arch}" --tag "${target}" --sdcard 1024M --device "${deviceType}"

EXPOSE 5554
EXPOSE 5555
EXPOSE 8554

CMD /usr/local/bin/start_emulator.sh
```

start_emulator.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "STARTING EMULATOR"
emulator -avd $DEVICE_NAME -gpu swiftshader_indirect -no-accel -camera-back none -camera-front none -no-audio -no-window -screen no-touch -no-snapstorage -no-snapshot -no-boot-anim -memory 4096 -wipe-data -skip-adb-auth &
echo "WAITING EMULATOR"
adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done; input keyevent 82'
adb shell wm dismiss-keyguard
adb shell settings put system screen_off_timeout 1800000
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
sleep 180
echo "EMULATOR BOOT FINISHED"
adb devices
adb logcat
```

GitLab-Runner Dockerfile

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest

ARG GITLAB_RUNNER_REGISTRATION_TOKEN
ARG BOT_TOKEN

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates && \
    apt-get install -y curl git && \
    apt-get install -y docker.io

RUN usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner

ENTRYPOINT ["gitlab-runner"]

RUN gitlab-runner register \
    --name mobile-runner \
    --non-interactive \
    --url "" \
    --registration-token $GITLAB_RUNNER_REGISTRATION_TOKEN \
    --env "BOT_TOKEN=$BOT_TOKEN" \
    --executor docker \
    --docker-privileged \
    --docker-image "docker:latest" \
    --docker-volumes "/cache" \
    --docker-volumes "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

CMD ["run", "--user=gitlab-runner"]
```

When I try to do "adb connect android-emulator:5555", the response is: Connection refused. So it sees the port. Maybe it is blocked somehow? But i exposed the ports i needed...

I use `docker compose up gitlab-runner` to start containers.

I also don't know if gitlab-runner creates containers for pipelines within the compose network. Maybe it doesn't work for this reason.

My host machine is MacOS, which means I can't use a ready-made image with the emulator because I don't have a Kernel-based Virtual Machine, as far as I understand